# Looking to convert integer as date SQL

Tags: sql

Looking to convert the integer '43676' and '43683' to a date. It's supposed to be '30-07-2019' and '06-08-2019' respectively, but SQL converts it into a wrong date when using e.g. `convert(datetime, '43683')`.

Comment: Date conversions are commonly database specific, what kind of database are you using?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be the number of days past since 1900-01-01, but odly offset by 2 days..

IN MS SQL you could use

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 43676-2, '1900-01-01')
```

OR

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 43683, '1899-12-30')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try -

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, 43676, '1899-12-30')
```

Result:

```
2019-07-30 00:00:00.000
```